# Pandas groupby on one column witout losing others columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with the groupby and pandas, at the beginning I have this chart :

```py
import pandas as pd 

data = {'Code_Name':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4] ,'Name':['Tom', 'Nicko', 'Krish','Jack kr','Tom', 'Nick', 'Krishx', 'Jacks'],'Cat':['A', 'B','C','D','A', 'B','C','D'], 'T':[9, 7, 14, 12,4, 3, 12, 11]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df

i have this : 
   Code_Name     Name Cat   T
0          1      Tom   A   9
1          2     Nick   B   7
2          3    Krish   C  14
3          4  Jack kr   D  12
4          1      Tom   A   4
5          2     Nick   B   3
6          3   Krishx   C  12
7          4    Jacks   D  11
```

Now i with groupby :

```py
df.groupby(['Code_Name','Name','Cat'],as_index=False)['T'].sum()

i got this:
   Code_Name     Name Cat   T
0          1      Tom   A  13
1          2     Nick   B  10
2          3    Krish   C  14
3          3   Krishx   C  12
4          4  Jack kr   D  12
5          4    Jacks   D  11
```

But for me , i need this result :

```py
   Code_Name   Name Cat   T
0          1    Tom   A  13
1          2   Nick   B  10
2          3  Krish   C  26
3          4   Jack   D  23
```

i don't care about **Name** the **Code_name** is only thing important for me with sum of T
Thank's

Comment: Desired output is of `df.groupby('Cat')['T'].sum()` yet you are grouping by three columns. How do you want to handle different names (i.e. `Krish` vs `Krishx`)?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Code_Name','Cat'],as_index=False)['T'].sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 ways - for each column with avoid losts add aggreation function - `first`, `last` or `', '.join` obviuosly for strings columns and aggregation dunctions like `sum`, `mean` for numeric columns:

```
df = df.groupby('Code_Name',as_index=False).agg({'Name':'first', 'Cat':'first', 'T':'sum'})
print (df)
   Code_Name     Name Cat   T
0          1      Tom   A  13
1          2    Nicko   B  10
2          3    Krish   C  26
3          4  Jack kr   D  23
```

Or if some values are duplicated per groups like here `Cat` values add this columns to `groupby` - only order should be changed in output:

```
df = df.groupby(['Code_Name','Cat'],as_index=False).agg({'Name':'first', 'T':'sum'})
print (df)
   Code_Name Cat     Name   T
0          1   A      Tom  13
1          2   B    Nicko  10
2          3   C    Krish  26
3          4   D  Jack kr  23
```

Comment: Thank's , i just modified your code and it's working for me !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the other variable then just group by the column of interest:

```py
gb = df.groupby(['Code_Name'],as_index=False)['T'].sum()
print(gb)
```

```
   Code_Name   T
0          1  13
1          2  10
2          3  26
3          4  23
```

Now to get your output, you can take the last value of Name for each group:

```py
gb = df.groupby(['Code_Name'],as_index=False).agg({'Name': 'last', 'Cat': 'first', 'T': 'sum'})
print(gb)
```

```
0          1     Tom   A  13
1          2    Nick   B  10
2          3  Krishx   C  26
3          4   Jacks   D  23
```

Comment: That's not working , because i'll lost my Name column and others columns

Comment: @jezrael I added it at the same time. Note that I used last instead of first, since it does not lead the required output.

Comment: Yes it was later but I wrote it without reading yours. Anyway, my bad for the `last` part, it seems that `first` works better.

Comment: yop, you are right, so rollback. If use some edit my name from your answer will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try:

```
    (df.groupby("Code_Name", as_index=False)
       .agg({"Name":"first", "Cat":"first", "T":"sum"}))
```

see link: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53405/pandas-dataframe-groupby-and-then-sum-multi-columns-sperately for the original answer